# Return Double from Boost thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

Hi I have an Boost thread which should return a double. The function looks like this:

```
void analyser::findup(const double startwl, const double max, double &myret){
  this->data.begin();
  for(int i = (int)data.size() ; i >= 0;i--){
    if(this->data[i].lambda > startwl){
      if(this->data[i].db >= (max-30)) {
        myret = this->data[i+1].lambda;
        std::cout <<"in thread " << myret << std::endl;
        return;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

this function is called by another function:

```
void analyser::start_find_up(const double startwl, const double max){
  double tmp = -42.0;
  boost::thread up(&analyser::findup,*this, startwl,max,tmp);
  std::cout << "before join " << tmp << std::endl;
  up.join();
  std::cout << "after join " << tmp << std::endl;
}
```

Anyway I've tried and googled almost anything but i can't get it to return a value.

The output looks like this right now.

```
before join -42
in thread 843.487
after join -42
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tmp` does not get the expected value after thread join because creating a boost::thread object copies all arguments to thread storage ([see documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.multiple_argument_constructor)).

You must encapsulate `tmp` with `boost::ref`, which has the effect of providing a "copy-constructible reference" (sorry if the terminology is inadequate, but that's the idea)

```
double tmp = -42.0;
boost::thread up(&analyser::findup,*this, startwl,max, boost::ref(tmp));
```

More on the [Thread Management documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html)

Comment: The specific thing to note is that the arguments are *copied*. Look at the [constructor notes](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.multiple_argument_constructor) in the documentation.

Comment: I've already approved your pending edit, and so I can't make my own edits to the question. Could you amend the question one more time so that the tags are *boost* and *c++*? The current tags are meaningless.

Comment: Thanks this was actually my "first time" to post