# Return Container from Boost Thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, dictionary

*Note* I have already looked at the answer found here: [Return Double from Boost thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156174/return-double-from-boost-thread), however the proposed solution doesn't work for me.

I have the following tid-bits of source code

```
   void run(int tNumber, std::vector<char *>files, std::map<std::basic_string,float>word_count)
    {

    boost::thread_group threads;

    std::map<std::basic_string,float> temp;

    for(int i = 0; i < tNumber; ++i)
        threads.create_thread(boost::bind(mtReadFile,files[i],boost::ref(word_count)));


    threads.join_all()
    }
```

This is the function that creates new threads for the calling process. These threads then call an instance of mtReadFile.

```
    void mtReadFile(char *filename, std::map<std::basic_string,float> word_count)
    {
          //function like things
    }
```

What I need to happen is word_count be returned from each thread to the calling process. I have tried the boost::ref in hopes of getting around the fact that boost threads copy all arguments to thread storage, but it has't worked for me.

Comment: Your word_count parameter is passed by value, not by reference, so it would not work even without the threading complication.  Note the reference parameter in the "double" example you cite.

Comment: I recognize that it is passed by value, not reference. In the example that I have cited, they encapsulate the argument to be passed by reference with the boost::ref identifier. In my source code I have added the same identifiers, without success.

Comment: They also define the thread function as `void function(const double input, double &output)`.  You need the function to accept the param by reference, AND `boost::ref()` to wrap your calling reference so that `boost::thread()` does not copy the value.  But seriously, make this work for a single thread, then do the multiple threads.

Comment: I didn't have the function accepting by reference. That's the little bit I was missing. Thanks for pointing that out. If you format the comment in the form of a response, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: std::basic_string is not a type, using char* as strings is dangerous, so the threading part is not your only problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your word_count parameter is passed by value, not by reference:

```
void mtReadFile(char *filename, std::map<std::basic_string,float> word_count)
```

instead of

```
void mtReadFile(char *filename, std::map<std::basic_string,float> &word_count)
```

This would fail to work even in the single-threaded case, which you should definitely test before attempting the more complex multithreading.

The function needs to accept a reference, AND you need `boost::ref()` to prevent `boost::thread()` from copying the parameter before the function invocation.